# Why there is no reputation change for comments

Tags: feature-request

I am an Stack Overflow user. There is reputation change for every Question and Answers.
Why there is no reputation change for a nice comments. some time i find a comment so nice that it is upvoted by many user. i feel points should be awarded in this case.

Comment: There is no reputation.. But there **is** a [silver badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/94/pundit) for when you get enough upvoted comments... The Pundit badge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments are transitory. They are there to help clarify a question / answer or add ancillary information to it. They are transitory and have always been seen as a second hand feature of the site.

If a comment is that important, is should be rolled into the post it is on - then deleted.

Giving reputation for comment would change their nature and dynamics, which we don't want. Don't forget - there are **no** downvotes on comments either, so how would you take reputation away from a user that posted a bad/unpopular comment?